# error: failed linking file resources. AAPT error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this error in main activity

> error: attribute 'com.galaxy.android.animals:menu' not found.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: attribute 'com.galaxy.android.animals:menu' not found., sources=[E:\Animals\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:136], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

My project got deleted so i used apk decompiler to decompile apk file which was presented in my phone now i am getting this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/my_drawer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#134563"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.galaxy.android.animals.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bgfour" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bg"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="wildanimals"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/wildanimals" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="birds"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/birds" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="wateranimals"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/wateranimals" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/days"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="amphibians"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/amphibians" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="farmanimals"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/farmanimals" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="petanimals"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/petanimals" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:onClick="insects"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/insects" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                        android:onClick="piano"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/animalspiano" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

   </RelativeLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:headerLayout="@layout/my_header"
    app:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/my_menu"/>
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

Comment: Check your main activity layout. line number 138

Comment: There is  this navigation view on 138

Comment: Is your my_menu at proper place? Check iy

Comment: I don't know  why but  'xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"' saying **Namespace declaration is never used**